How to open both a file and the encompassing project using vscode://
Currently, I'm using open vscode://file/<full path> but this would open only the file but not the encompassing project folder.
I wonder if there's a URL that would open both the file and the encompassing project.
I'm unable to execute code because the app I'm working on won't have the permission to execute an arbitrary command line due to Mac's App Sandbox.
This is for Mac. Thank you.
